# Drag&Drop feature in jquery drops element at seemingly random position

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I got some problem with my code but I simply cannot put my finger on what would be at fault in that situation I am lost.

So the situation is as follows, I am making a simple drag and drop interface by using jquery, all it does is: Make a grid, add/remove "pawns" depending on a certain table in the same page and drag&drop whatever pawn you want in whatever square you wish to. Everything works as expected but almost always when I try to drop the pawn on a square it teleports in a random position, rarely it does drop where it is expected to. I am not sure it is relevant but I am using laravel 10 and this is a blade file, Any suggestions I could try?

````
<div class="col-md-3 gridframe">
            <h3 class="text-center">Character Grid</h3>
            <div id="grid" class="row mx-auto">
            </div>
        </div>

<style>
    .gridframe {
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden; 
    }

    .grid-cell {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    .character {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 999;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
    }

</style>

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function insertCharacter(nickname, hp) {
        var cells = $('.grid-cell');
        cells.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).children('.character').length) {
                var row = $(this).data('row');
                var col = $(this).data('col');
                $(this).append('<div class="character" data-hp="' + hp + '">' + nickname + '<br>' + hp + '</div>');
                return false; 
            }
        });

        // make characters draggable 
        $('.character').draggable({
            revert: 'invalid',
            zIndex: 100,
            start: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
            }
        });

        // make grid cells droppable
        $('.grid-cell').droppable({
            accept: '.character',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var character = ui.draggable;
                // var characterHP = character.data('hp');
                character.appendTo($(this)); 
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#character-table tbody').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'tr', function() {
            var nickname = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var hp = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
            insertCharacter(nickname, hp);
        });

        $('#character-table tbody').on('DOMNodeRemoved', 'tr', function() {
            var nickname = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
            $('.character').each(function() {
                if ($(this).text().includes(nickname)) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        });

        var gridSize = 10; 
        var grid = $('#grid');
        for (var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
                $('<div class="grid-cell" data-row="' + i + '" data-col="' + j + '"></div>').appendTo(grid);
            }
        }
    });
    </script>```
````

Comment: Please use the Code Snippet feature (it allows you to specify HTML, CSS, and JS separately) to include your code in the question. This will allow us to run that snippet and easily see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, getting `draggable` and `droppable` to work together has the same inconsistencies you mention. Unless they are required, I would suggest trying [sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable) instead. Sortable functions very similar to draggable + droppable and allows you to link multiple containers using the `connectWith` property.

Here is a simple example:

```js
let gridSize = 5,
    characters = [
      { name: 'Frodo', hp: 100, type: 'hobbit' },
      { name: 'Data', hp: 105, type: 'android' },
      { name: 'Spiderman', hp: 62, type: 'human' }
    ];

$('.grid')
  .css(`grid-template-columns`, `repeat(${gridSize}, 4rem)`)
  .html([...Array(gridSize**2)].map(() => '<div class="cell"></div>').join(''));

$('.characters')
  .html(characters.map((character) =>
    `<div class="character"><div class="stats"><p>${character.name}</p><p>hp: ${character.hp}</p></div></div>`).join(``))
  .add('.grid .cell')
  .sortable({
    connectWith: '.characters, .grid .cell',
    cursor: 'grabbing',
    receive: (e, ui) => {
      if(ui.item.parent().hasClass('cell')) {
        let $cell = $(e.target),
            $character = ui.item,
            $characters = $cell.find('.character').not($character),
            coords = [$cell.index() % gridSize, Math.floor($cell.index() / gridSize)];
        //do stuff
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.grid{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;}
  
.grid .cell{
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: visible;}
  
.grid .cell:has(.character):hover{
  border-width: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}
  
.characters{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  min-width: 6rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;}
 
.character{
  align-items: end;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  height: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3rem;}
  
.character .stats{
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 4px;}

.character p{
  font-size: .66rem;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="characters"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems much more manageable, thanks. I'd later like to store the position of the pawns to a database in order to retrieve them from there. How can I do this? I didn't se any "x,y" elements. on the pawns/grid.